# Mock promise that never resolves with Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

With Jest, is there a way to mock a promise that never resolves? I want to write a snapshot test where I verify my UI in a loading state. The loading state depends on a promise. If the promise resolves, the loading state goes away.

Template:

```html
<div v-if="isLoading">
  <div>Starting service, please wait</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
async startService() {
    try {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const response = await this.service.start();
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
```

Proposed test:

```
it('loading screen should display', async() => {
  const startServiceSpy = jest
    .spyOn(Service.prototype, 'start')
    .mockImplementation(() =>
      DO NOT RESOLVE SERVICE CALL HERE
    }));

  wrapper.vm.startService();

  // show loading screen in snapshot
  expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();

});
```

Comment: `.mockReturnValue(new Promise(() => {}))`? Or look up the "deferred pattern" which gives you the ability to resolve or reject it at will.

Comment: You can't `await wrapper.vm.startService();` if you never resolve the `service.start()` promise.

Comment: @Bergi I removed await from the test service call.